# Avoid expanding combo box on 'focus' or 'onclick' event

Tags: extjs

Team,

I am having one problem where I donot want to expand combo box on certain flag and want to display the alert message.

there is no event like onClick in EXTJS so I tried with focus event but still combo box is expanding.

code

```
focus:function() {
    if(this.store.baseParams.donotExpandFlag) {
           alert("I should not expand this combo");
           // What to do here and out side of IF block so that there is conditional expansion          
    }              
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specifiy your ExtJS version and please format your code.

Here is what you can do for ExtJS4.x

Manually set/unset the `isExpanded` property. That should work (untested)

for ExtJS3.x you will have to override the the `isExpanded()` method and in additon apply a custom flag which indicates blocked/auto and get checked before the default code gets executed.

You may try this (untested)

```
_isExpanded:  true, // true means block, false auto
isExpanded: function(){
    return this._isExpanded || (this.list && this.list.isVisible());
},
```

No, this works. See the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/nfrz5/2/)** for ExtJS3.4

Second **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/nfrz5/3/)** for ExtJS3.4 with a form

Comment: I tried this and didnot work. I am using EXTJS 3. Any other alrenatives.

Comment: @user1913742 No, this is working. I've added a working example

Comment: It is not working. I tried even stanalone example from JSFiddle. EXTJS version is 3.2 and I am using xtype combo I gave alert in the isExpanded function and alert it self is not called.

Comment: @user1913742 Well, it **is** working in JSFiddle so I guess you should check your code/implementation if it is not working for you. But that leaves the error in your code/implementation.

Comment: It seems it only works if we create combo box using constructor. I hardcode _isExpanded:true for one of the combo box xtype:combo and still it is expanding

Comment: @user1913742 Please check my second JSFiddle. I placed them into a form as config objects.

Comment: Only difference I see now is my combo box is remote and is making AJAX call.I will try demo code and post updates.

Comment: I tried this and kept same peace of code in my combo box. I kept _isExpanded:true initially and kept same function as given but found I am getting this.list is null or not an object. Even I tried returning 'true' from the function all the time but same error. I guess it has something to do with AJAX call where list is not initialized or some thing. I think it only fails with remote stores.